# Excel add-in not loading when opening Excel from VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm using excel [reg-ex add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) and it works well, the only problem with it that it doesn't load when excel is started by VBA.

I've a macro in word to collect some data in Word and copy it to excel, this one starts excel, the output is fine, but I need to restart excel to be able to use the add-in (it's enabled in the options, just not loading).

I've tried another macro: just open excel and create a new workbook and it has the same issue.

I've only this one 3rd party add-in so I can't compare to other ones.

Any idea?

Comment: You'd probably get a better response to this at stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes after posting I've also felt that probably would be a better place. Is it fair to post the same question there too?

Comment: No, you should delete this one if you post over there.

Comment: Take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213375/loading-addins-when-excel-is-instantiated-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it based on answer posted to a similar question in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/806720/4721734

> I looked into this problem again, and the Application.Addins
>   collection seems to have all the addins listed in the Tools->Addins
>   menu, with a boolean value stating whether or not an addin is
>   installed. So what seems to work for me now is to loop through all
>   addins and if .Installed = true then I set .Installed to False and
>   back to True, and that seems to properly load my addins.
>
> ```
> Function ReloadXLAddins(TheXLApp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
>
>     Dim CurrAddin As Excel.AddIn
>
>     For Each CurrAddin In TheXLApp.AddIns
>         If CurrAddin.Installed Then
>             CurrAddin.Installed = False
>             CurrAddin.Installed = True
>         End If
>     Next CurrAddin
>
> End Function
> ```

Answer (score 1):

That is how it is supposed to work.

From COM docs.

```
      Component Automation  
Exposing the Application Object  

 Language Filter: All Language Filter: Multiple Language Filter: Visual Basic Language Filter: C# Language Filter: C++ Language Filter: J# Language Filter: JScript  
 Visual Basic (Declaration) 
 Visual Basic (Usage) 
 C# 
 C++ 
 J# 
 JScript 

Any document-based, user-interactive applications that expose ActiveX objects should have one top-level object named the Application object. This object is initialized as the active object when an application starts.

The Application object identifies the application and provides a way for ActiveX clients to bind to and navigate the application's exposed objects. All other exposed objects are subordinate to the Application object; it is the root-level object in the object hierarchy.

The names of the Application object's members are part of the global name space, so ActiveX clients do not need to qualify them. For example, if MyApplication is the name of the Application object, a Visual Basic program can refer to a method of MyApplication as MyApplication.MyMethod or simply MyMethod. However, you should be careful not to overload the Application object with too many members because it can cause ambiguity and decrease performance. A large, complicated application with many members should be organized hierarchically, with a few generalized objects at the top, branching out into smaller, more specialized objects. 

The following chart shows how applications should expose their Application and Document objects.

Command line  Multiple-document interface application  Single-document interface application  
/Embedding 
 Expose class factories for document classes, but not for the application.

Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object.
 Expose class factories for document class, but not for the application.

Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object.

/Automation 
 Expose class factories for document classes.

Expose class factory for the application using RegisterClassObject.

Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object.
 Do not expose class factory for document class.

Expose class factory for the Application object using RegisterClassObject.

Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object.

No OLE switches 
 Expose class factories for document classes, but not for the application.

Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object.
 Call RegisterActiveObject for the Application object. 


The call to RegisterActiveObject enters the Application object in OLE's running object table (ROT), so ActiveX clients can retrieve the active object instead of creating a new instance. Visual Basic applications can use the GetObject statement to access an existing object.

 © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

So /a or /embedding won't load anything but the bare app (and /a is also a good troubleshooting step).

Start your app, then GetObject on it.

Also there is little reason to use such as addin as you can do the exact thing the addin is doing. This is vbs (so pastable into VBA) using the same RegEx engine as your addin (Word also has it's own RegEx engine called `Use Wildcards`). Set a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5`.

```
Set regEx1 = New RegExp
If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "i") > 0 then
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
Else
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
End If 
If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "v") > 0 then
    IncExc = False
Else
    IncExc = True
End If 
regEx1.Global = False
regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    If RegEx1.Test(Line) = IncExc then
        outp.writeline Line
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I've found the answer referenced by ZygD to be easier. I use the add-in as it has also a find/replace form capable of regular expressions, not only the support in VBA.